# Boolean in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I see an issue in Cassandra boolean datatype,

I have a table with one field as boolean

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.issuetable (
    "partitionId" text,
    "name" text,
    "field" text,
    "testboolean" boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY ("partitionId", "name"));
```

Now when I try to insert in table, I didn't add the boolean 'testboolean'

```
    INSERT into keyspace.issuetable("partitionId", "name", "field")
VALUES ('testpartition', 'cluster1_name','testfiled');
```

**Issue** :

1) If the boolean entry (say testboolean entry) in INSERT query is not added so as per the data type it needs to be 'false' but it is added as **null**

```
SELECT * FROM issuetable ;

 partitionId   | name          | field     | testboolean
---------------+---------------+-----------+-------------
 testpartition | cluster1_name | testfiled |        null
```

Could you someone explain why? Also let me know the solution to solve this, I expect 'false' not 'null'

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra is not like the traditional SQL databases. It does not store rows in tables. The best way to think about Cassandra's data model is to imagine a `sortedMap<rowKey, map<columnKey, value>>`.

This means that any particular row is not required to have the same fields/columns as any other one. In your example the inserted row simply **does not have** a property named `testboolean`.

To understand more I can recommend referring [here](https://teddyma.gitbooks.io/learncassandra/content/model/data_model_and_cql.html).
And no, you cannot set a default value for a column (or rather you can do it only on application side).

Comment: why does it has datatype as a feature in Cassandra?  It throws the error If I insert a wrong data type. Why not it stores the data as an object (i.e any data type) like Mongo?

Comment: Using typed data & table schemas is just a design decision (you could ask the same question about Postgres or any other typed database). Prior to 3.0, Cassandra actually did support untyped data sets, however this functionality was not supported by the new storage engine introduced in 3.0.

You can read more about the design of the storage engine [here](https://www.datastax.com/2015/12/storage-engine-30)

Comment: what Justin said and I could only add that having defined schema allows for multiple optimization in compaction and overall database performance. And also thinking about mongo as a fully schema-less storage is not entirely correct. If you were to achieve what you attempted here with mongo you would have to define schema and/or indexes if you needed querying using such secondary fields.